# can't save picture to database

Tags: c#, sql, database

Database is .mdf, 
datatype of column is varchar << must be used as project requirement

I input textFilePath.text that I generate from `txtFilePath.Text = open.FileName;`, but it makes an error when I press button input. The error that is displayed on the line `cmd.CommandText` is

> Sqlexception is unhandled : String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

But if I replace the `textFilePath.text` with other string it will be success to input to the database.

This is the code, thanks for helping me.

```
private void Save()
{
    txtFilePath.Text.ToString();
    cn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into Inventory (ID,Item,Gender,Qty,Price,FilePath) values('" + txtID.Text + "','" + txtItem.Text + "','" + Gender + "','" + numQty.Value + "','" + numPrice.Value + "','" + txtFilePath.Text + "')";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Clone();
    cn.Close();
}

private void ButtonChoose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // open file dialog
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        // image filters
        open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp";

        if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // display image in picture box
            pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
            // image file path
            txtFilePath.Text = open.FileName;

        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Image loading error....");
    }
}

private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtID.Text != "" & txtItem.Text != "" & Gender != "" & numPrice.Value > 0 & numQty.Value > 0 & txtFilePath.Text != "")
    {
        Save();
        MessageBox.Show("Recorded");
        gridViewLoad();

    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("all field must be filled");
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# store a picture to database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961071/c-sharp-store-a-picture-to-database)

Comment: What part of the error message is confusing?  It says that the data you are trying to put in the column in larger than the column can hold.

Comment: @Plutonix - The title of this post is a little misleading. He's not trying to save a picture to the database. It looks more like he's trying to save a path to the database. That question is not a duplicate.

Comment: You are right, sorry for asking this easy problem. i'm a newbe. thanks for the guidance

Comment: Check the column size of `FilePath` and then check the `txtFilePath.Text` values length and you shoul see why the exception is thrown

Comment: possible duplicate of [error, string or binary data would be truncated when trying to insert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591473/error-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-when-trying-to-insert)

Answer (score 1):

The error as Golden Dragon said is that you are trying to **INSERT INTO** the table **Inventory** a **string bigger than the allowed size of the table field**.

To solve it you should **increase the size of the field FilePath in the database**.

It's also important to point out that running a query with string concatenation is a huge security flaw, see [SQL Injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) for more information.

You should always use parameterized querys as in the example:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
    command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = customerID;

    // Use AddWithValue to assign Demographics.
    // SQL Server will implicitly convert strings into XML.
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@demographics", demoXml);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        Int32 rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("RowsAffected: {0}", rowsAffected);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

From: [MSDN - SqlCommand.Parameters Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)

The example also shows how to use a connection with using (avoiding not closing the connection if an error occurs).

In your case it would be:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    string commandText = "insert into Inventory (ID,Item,Gender,Qty,Price,FilePath) values(@ID, @Item, @Gender, @Qty, @Price, @FilePath)";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);

    command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtID.Text;
    ...
    command.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.Decimal, 11, 4).Value = numPrice.Value;
    ...

    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Eka Soedono Please try the below code and let me know if it works.

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into Inventory (ID,Item,Gender,Qty,Price,@path); 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@path",txtFilePath.Text);
```